# Helm use values between backticks in IngressRoute definition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, traefik

So I have this IngressRoute:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: webserver
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`api.{{ .Values.domain }}`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: webserver-service
      port: 80
```

The problem is that the rendered template shows

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: webserver
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`api.`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: webserver-service
      port: 80
```

I want to use the value from **domain** to create the whole `Host` definition, but I can't seem to make it work. Do you have any ideas on how can I use `{{ .Values.domain }}` between backticks?

Comment: Can you share a minimized version of your values file?

Comment: Since the backticks are outside a `{{ ... }}` template expression, they have no syntactic meaning at all.  Does your chart's `values.yaml` file have a top-level `domain` setting?  Are you in some other context (maybe a `range` loop) that redefines `.`?

Comment: Did you eventually solve the problem? Having the same issue here.